# CQWP Get Author Information

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I've got a content query web part displaying items from a list which includes an author column.  I've managed to get the author's name and picture displaying, but I don't know how to get their department.

Currently I have this in my ItemStyle:

```
<xsl:template name="Testimonial" match="Row[@Style='Testimonial']" mode="itemstyle">
  <xsl:variable name="UserFieldLogin">
     <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UserLookup(string(@Person) ,'Login')" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="UserPicture" select="translate($UserFieldLogin,'\','_')"/>

  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"><img src="https://staffurl/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/{$UserPicture}_LThumb.jpg" alt="" style="width:62px;"/></div>
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="@Person" /></h4>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Testimonial" disable-output-escaping="yes" />      
  <br /><br />
</xsl:template>
```

Can someone assist me in looking up other fields for the author??

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The department will not be available in the same way sadly.

Create a placeholder using your XSLT then add some jQuery to the page and use that to grab the department using SPServices or similar then insert into the placeholder.

Comment: It's a shame there's not a better way to do this, but thanks for your suggestion - I'll have to give it go.